# free trial subscription disabled because no credit left

Tags: azure, azure-free-services

I am new to Azure and while trying things I have created and deleted several resources and now my subscription is disable because I do not have any credits left.
I thought when I delete a resource I have created by mistake the credit will restore as well, its not true?
what should I do now?

Comment: Not true. Credit means you don't need to pay for first $200 of usage, it doesn't revert. You'll probably have to add a credit card to continue using the subscription (it'll charge your card).

Answer (score 2):

- When you create a new Azure Resource you start getting billed.
- When you delete a resource the billing for that resource stops, but remember you will be charged for the time the resource was active.
- If the total of all the charges exceeds your limit, the account will ask for Credit Card details to start charging it.
- You can go the **Cost Management + Billing** section in Azure portal to get details of all the charges incurred for that Subscription.